# Suggest a way around this callback not letting my constructor set values

Tags: javascript

I have a user

```
user = new User('name','pwd');
```

which should contain a `valid` property

```
var User = module.exports = function User(username, password){
    db.query('MATCH (user) WHERE user.username={username} RETURN user',
        {username:username},
        function(err,result){                            // << The callback
            if(err) return console.log('error: '+err);      
            if(result[0])
                this.valid=true;                         // << this.value
            if(result[0].user.data.hash == crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password+result[0].user.data.salt,'utf8').digest('hex')) 
                this.authenticated=true;
        }
    );
}
```

But since `this.valid` is called from within a callback of the `db.query`, it doesn't execute before the `new` object is already returned without `this.valid`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196), regarding `this`.

However, the bigger problem, as you already mentioned, is rather that `db.query` is asynchronous, i.e. even if the object is created, you cannot immediately use it because the values won't be set yet. Instead, you should create a factory function, which makes the `db.query` call, creates the `User` instance and pass it to a callback. This way you can be sure that the `User` object is fully populated.

Example:

```
function User(valid, authenticated) {
    this.valid = valid;
    this.authenticated = authenticated;
}

function createUser(username, password, callback) {
    db.query(..., ..., function(err, result) {
        var valid = ...;
        var authenticated = ...;
        callback(new User(valid, authenticated));
    });
}

createUser('foo', 'bar', function(user) {
    // do something with user
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to have access to your this context object:

```
var User = module.exports = function User(username, password){
    var $this = this;
    db.query('MATCH (user) WHERE user.username={username} RETURN user',
        {username:username},
        function(err,result){                            // << The callback
            if(err) return console.log('error: '+err);      
            if(result[0])
                $this.valid=true;                         // << this.value
            if(result[0].user.data.hash == crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password+result[0].user.data.salt,'utf8').digest('hex')) 
                $this.authenticated=true;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem: *"But since `this.valid` is called from within a callback of the `db.query`, it doesn't execute before the new object is already returned without `this.valid`. What can I do?"*